# is there a list of jquery names or reserved words or a naming convention for expantions?

Tags: jquery

I want to (or do already) extend jQuery with some user defined extensions. eg. a "one function access" to radio buttons os selects (using `jQuery.fn.my_func ....`).

Here is my question: how to name them? because the names like get/value and so on are allready used. Is there a naming convention like a user prefix (ie. xy_value), or at least a list of names jQuery allready uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no global jQuery registry I'm aware of that would give you a 100% safe way of choosing a non-conflicting set of names.  What is generally done and generally works out fine is to pick a prefix that is related to your project and is not a common english noun or verb and then start every method with that prefix such as:

```
jQuery.fn.jlfCookieGet = function() {};
jQuery.fn.jlfCookieSet = function() {};
jQuery.fn.jlfCookieRemove = function() {};
```

Or, you can create your own unique name from scratch name (like "jQuery" did) and use that as the prefix.

```
jQuery.fn.chocChipGet = function() {};
jQuery.fn.chocChipSet = function() {};
jQuery.fn.chocChipRemove = function() {};
```

FYI, it is simple enough with a piece of test code in a sample app or in a jsFiddle to see if jQuery is already using any particular name you're thinking about:

```
if (jQuery.fn.whatever) {
    // name already in use
}
```

You could also simply enumerate all symbols already in use on `jQuery.fn` with code like this:

```
for (var name in jQuery.fn) {
    console.log(name);
}
```

You can see this list here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TSR7d/

Comment: thx,this is  my answer; there is no std. or a register "name" logic like in domains;  I use my Initials - as always, thanks (get a list of ___proto___ i get red, should have had the idea my self)